# parse specific data using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: xml, linq, parsing, html-agility-pack

i succeed getting values from the web in the a[@href] but with all the values i received some are not needed. I saw in the web source that the elements i don't want are as follow:

`<a href="http//www.notneeded.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxgcid=C12289x460&amp;keyword=xxxxxxx">1,507 available from $122</a>"`

and all the values that i needed were like this:

```
<a href="http//differenturl.com/xxx/xxx/_/id/245/xxxx;xxxx">needed value;M</a>
```

all the needed values were starting like this exactly:

```
<a href="http://differenturl.com/xxx/xxx/
```

and then the id and the values were obviously different with what i need.

Please tell me how to i set in the code that i will have instead of all the "a hrefs", the specific a hrefs that their value starts with "http://differenturl.com/xxx/xxx/"

sorry for my english.

here is the code:

```
var teams = from hyperlink in teamTags.SelectNodes(".//a[@href]")
                    where hyperlink != null
                    select hyperlink.InnerText;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using XPath `starts-with()` or `contains()` function to match `href` attribute value partially, for example  :

```
.//a[starts-with(@href, 'http://differenturl.com/xxx/xxx/')]
```

Comment: Dude you are the king! It worked!!!
Do you give online guiding by any chance? contact my email if you want to make some extra money.
Thanks again!